# How to set layout based on a database value in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, layout

I need to switch the layout based on a user value that is stored in the database.  I would like to set this using a plugin (tried PreDispatch hook).  However, it looks like I can't access the models there as yet.  At what point can I access db values and set the layout?  I prefer to do this globally rather than set for each controller.  Ideas appreciated.

Comment: preDispatch should work fine. How were you trying to access the models and what error(s) did you get?

Comment: Turns out my main problem is routing, the model works in my preDispatch.  I will post the routing question separately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For such purposes better to use controller plugin

```
class Core_Controller_Plugin_LayoutManager extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeStartup (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        // Get your layout name here

        $this->_layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()
            ->setLayoutPath(YOUR_PATH_HERE)
            ->setLayout(YOUR_LAYOT_NAME_HERE);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add in in config:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.templatemanager = Core_Controller_Plugin_LayoutManager
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  As I wrote above, the main problem is routing.  Once I figure that out I will try using a controller plugin as you suggest, looks good.